# Cant boot from USB

Tags: boot, windows-7, usb-drive, usb-installation

I tried to install ubuntu alongside with Windows 8, but for some reason, it just deleted the W8 installation. But now, i want windows back, because Wine cant emulate all programs, which is, of course, to be expected. BUT: Even though i created the USB key with WinUSB (http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/winusb-create-bootable-windows-installer-usb-in-ubuntu-linux/) my computer won't boot from it! I have changed the boot order, tried to use boot menu, but i am all out of ideas :(
The USB key is a Kingston DataTraveller 32GB USB3, formatted as NTFS and all the windows files on it (Note, i am trying to install Windows 7), so i don't understand where it went wrong.
I hope you guys/girls have some ideas :)

Jonas Strand

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Ubuntu install deleted Win8? When installing alongside an existing Windows, it should not touch Windows at all. It might just be a grub issue. In a terminal, type `sudo update-grub` then reboot. You should see an entry for your Win8.

If, in fact, the Ubuntu installer DID remove your Win8, and you have to reinstall Windows via USB, your USB stick has to be formatted as Fat32, not NTFS.

Comment: Are you sure it has to be FAT32? The way i remember it is, that Windows 7 needs NTFS USB key to boot, but i can be mistaken, heh ^

Comment: You may be correct about NTFS. But I would try with a Fat32 stick and test it too.

Comment: This is what comes when i try to start Win8 from grub: http://www.the-strand.dk/pic.jpg

Comment: UEFI. Worst "improvement" ever. I am not sure I can help with this, but I bet Win8 is still on your hard drive. Are there any mountable folders/drives in Nautilus? If so, these are likely the Win8 install. If not, then something happened during the Ubuntu installation that really did remove Win8.

Comment: Alrigt, its not because am killing myself because i lost the win8 install (its win8 after all), but do you have any idea why i can't boot from USB? I am using the program WinUSB, link above, which formats it automatically as NTFS. But, if i were to format as FAT32, how to? I am complete Ubuntu/Linux noob ^ EDIT: Sorry for not answering your question, no, there is only "Reserved for system" :(

Comment: I agree about Win8...but that's another story...

As for booting, in UEFI there should be an option to boot first from device of your choice. Plug in the USB stick, then reboot, and it should show up in the UEFI. See if that works.

Comment: That is what i mean with "Boot menu", i see the USB drive, all right, i select it and clicks enter, so far so good, but when it tries to boot, nothing happens, it just loads GRUB :/

Comment: Weird. You have gone into the BIOS/UEFI, yes? It is either 'Delete' or 'F1' (usually Delete) to get into it. Then choose your first boot device.

Comment: Yep, indeed the case. I dont understand it either, as i used the exact same USB key to install Ubuntu from :S

Comment: Can you choose to change between UEFI and good old BIOS? I wonder if that would get things moving.

Comment: Well, i have to option to disable UEFI, if that is what you mean? And i have just fetched another USB key, so ill try to copy Win7 to it and check if it is the key's fault :)

Comment: Yes. And good idea getting another USB stick. Something might have written wrong on the first one, causing all the complications.

Comment: Alright, so far so good, now I can skip grub, but I get stuck on, what appears to be equal to BSoD on earlier windows versions. I get this error: 0xc000000e. But I can't boot from the new USB either :(

Comment: I am now out of suggestions.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that :(